# How to get values from the store in extjs4

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I have a store that fetches data from the zend server. I want to get the store records to do some customizations on my form. For getting data from store i am using the below code.

```
var index = Ext.StoreMgr.lookup('product.AttributeComboBox').find('abbr',4);
var reco = Ext.StoreMgr.lookup('product.AttributeComboBox').getAt(index);
```

Above snippet returns no records. Please let me know where i am wrong.

Comment: Is your store loaded at the time this lookup is made? Also, just as a tip, you can use findRecord() to accomplish the same thing, but with one less line of code.

Comment: Are you sure your store data got loaded properly? If you run count() on the store, does it indicate there are records? Also, you could just do console.log(store) and check in firebug if there's any data loaded in it to be sure.

Comment: Please post the response's body for the request to the zend server so we can see the data in the store.

Answer (score 1):

1. In your debugger check the store exists

   Ext.StoreMgr.lookup('product.AttributeComboBox')
2. Check how many records are in the store

   Ext.StoreMgr.lookup('product.AttributeComboBox').data.items
3. Check the records have parsed properly

What came from the server for the record

```
Ext.StoreMgr.lookup('product.AttributeComboBox').data.items[0].raw
```

How it get converted into the record

```
Ext.StoreMgr.lookup('product.AttributeComboBox').data.items[0].data
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us more code ?

So far, seems ok but you will have to check if the store have been created and if it has all the records, just like RichH said.

To check if the Store exists I would do

```
var productStore = Ext.getStore('product.AttributeComboBox');
console.log(productStore );
```

To check if the store is loaded

```
console.log(productStore.getCount());
```

To find the record

```
console.log(productStore.findRecord('abbr','4'));
```